# javascript escaping //

Tags: javascript

how will i escape the slashes // in javascript

```
var j = /^(ht|f)tp(s?)://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w-./?%&=]*)?$;/
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a `\` for escaping, like this:

```
var j = /^(ht|f)tp(s?):\/\/([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(\/[\w-./?%&=]*)?$;/
```